# Writing thunk for __thiscall

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86

I'm trying to write a thunk for __thiscall using a struct.

I've tested this struct and it works:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Thunk
{
   unsigned short leaECX;       
   unsigned long pThis;     
   unsigned char movEAX;       
   unsigned long pMemFunc;    
   unsigned short jmpEAX;       
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I fill this struct with the following bytecode (which I found online):

```
//Load effective address of this to ECX
//because __thiscall expect to get 'this' in ECX
leaECX = 0x0D8D;
pThis = here goes 'this' pointer;
//Move member function pointer to EAX
movEAX = 0xB8;
pMemFunc = here goes pointer to member function;
//Jump to member function
jmpEAX = 0xE0FF;
```

My question is can the movEAX and jmpEAX instructions be replaced with bytecode for assembly `call` instruction ?

If so how do I do it ?

I'm allocating this struct using `VirtualAlloc` and this flags `MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`.

Is this a compact way or does it waste memory (allocate whole page instead of `sizeof(Thunk)`) ?

Comment: I see two questions here.  The second one should be answerable simply by reading the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which says allocations are 1 page in size (default: 4K), aligned on an allocation granularity boundary (default: 64k http://stackoverflow.com/q/438863/845092)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `call` but then of course execution will return to your thunk so you need more code afterwards. Also if you get rid of the `mov` I assume you will want to do the `call address` variant, in which case be mindful of the fact that that uses relative encoding, so you can't just poke your address into memory.

You can switch to relative jump to get rid of the `mov`, using something like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Thunk
{
   unsigned short leaECX;       
   unsigned long pThis;     
   unsigned char jmp; 
   unsigned long pOffset;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

//Load effective address of this to ECX
//because __thiscall expect to get 'this' in ECX
leaECX = 0x0D8D;
pThis = here goes 'this' pointer;
jmp = 0xE9;
pOffset = (char*)address_of_member - (char*)&thunk.pOffset - 4;
```

Since memory protections are page granular you will need at least a page (`VirtualAlloc` does round up for you automatically). If you have multiple thunks you can of course pack them into the same page.

Comment: If I understand correctly if I replace movEAX+jmpEAX with call I'll have do add some code after call ? If so is it better to leave it as it is now ?

Comment: Yes, the difference between `call` and `jmp` is that `call` will return to your thunk so you can do further processing. If you don't need that, then leave it `jmp`. You can use the relative `jmp` to get rid of the `mov` if you want, but then you need to calculate the offset.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do this calculation ? As it works now after my thunk get executed and calls member function program's flow return to the point after the thunk was called. If I've used `call` program's flow will return to the thunk itself ?

Comment: Updated answer. Yes, with `call` flow would return to thunk which should eventually do a `ret` itself and that would return to the caller.

Comment: ATL's thunk relative `jmp` offset is: address_of_member - (pThunk+sizeof(Thunk)). Is it the same as your calculation ?

Comment: Yes, as long as the offset is at the end of the struct because that uses the size of the whole struct. Also be mindful about C pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Is `-4` from your pointer arithmetic example is the result of sizeof(pOffset) ? I mean why is it magic number ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Technically the offset is relative to the next instruction that would follow the `jmp`, that is how much extra adjustment needs to be applied to the instruction pointer in addition to incrementing by the size of the current instruction (the cpu automatically does that).